# Is there any Plugin available for VueJs in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans-8, vuejs2

Netbeans 8.x intellisense doesn't identify VueJS tags. Is there any Plugin available for VueJs syntax highlighting or autofill support in Netbeans 8.x? If not, are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 59):

`.vue` file is a kind of html file, you can add syntax highlighting in Netbeans :

- Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files
- Add a new file extension :

  - File Extension : *vue*
  - Associated File Type (MIME) : *HTML Files (text/html)*

Not perfect but it seems there is no plugin for this actually.

EDIT : Visual Studio Code has nice features for vuejs

Comment: To help reduce some of the warnings of invalid syntax you can add `nbproject/customs.json` with the content: `{
    "elements": {},
    "attributes": {
        "v-if": {},
        "@submit.prevent": {
            "context": "form"
        },
        "@click": {},
        "@keyup.enter": {},
        "scoped": {
            "context": "style"
        },
        "v-for": {},
        "v-model": {}
    }
}`

Comment: You can also click on the errors and do things like add the template tag. Or disable JavaScript validation. Defeats the purpose of the IDE a bit, but it might be preferred to seeing the error messages.

Comment: Custom Elements & Attributes in HTML in NetBeans IDE:

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/custom-elements-attributes-in-html-in-netbeans-ide

Comment: @KevinAndrews, where do I must put the nbproject/customs.json ?

Comment: @mhaniff  Usually it's in the folder where your source code is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin but it is still in developtment: https://github.com/Zwaen91/vuejs-netbeans. Some problems with the mixed mimetype text/vue+html. Created a ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-88

Comment: New mixed mimetype is needed to have a separate icon for vue files.